# MySQL: update multiple rows where new value needs to be dynamically calculated (subtraction of old value by a fixed number)

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a table with the following rows (only very few shown just to make the point):

```
id      created                     metadata_id start                       mean    min     max     last_reset                  state   sum
425609  2021-11-14 16:00:11.111377  133         2021-11-14 15:00:00.000000  NULL    NULL    NULL    1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000  364.33  224.10999999999999
425773  2021-11-14 17:00:11.159665  133         2021-11-14 16:00:00.000000  NULL    NULL    NULL    1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000  364.49  224.27
   ===> sum column rows above (before) this line are fine, sum column rows below (after) this line are *WRONG*<===
425937  2021-11-14 18:00:11.045548  133         2021-11-14 17:00:00.000000  NULL    NULL    NULL    2021-06-04 00:00:00.000000  364.67  588.99
426106  2021-11-14 19:00:11.148599  133         2021-11-14 18:00:00.000000  NULL    NULL    NULL    2021-06-04 00:00:00.000000  364.86  589.1799999999998
```

I now need to change

- the value of the column "sum"
- of all rows where id greater than 425773 and metadata_id=133
- and the new value needs to be "dynamically" calculated depending on the current/old value

Examples for point 3 of above requirements:

1. old (wrong) value is "588.99", correct reduced value (always minus exactly 364.54) should be "224,45".
2. old value 589.1799999999998 minus 364.54 gives new value of 224.6399999999998

So I need

1. syntax of changing multiple rows with
2. some kind of "live calculation" (new value based on old value minus fixed number)

**SQL experts very welcome.** My 9 years old little MySQL knowledge never was capable of doing such advanced stuff tbh.

**Update: answered by my own. Very simple:**

`UPDATE statistics SET sum=sum-364.54 WHERE metadata_id=133 AND id > 425773;`

Answer (score 0):

**Update: answered by my own. Very simple:**

```
UPDATE statistics SET sum=sum-364.54 WHERE metadata_id=133 AND id > 425773;
```